# I need advice for creating native Wordpress directory site based on native Wordpress functionality only

Tags: directory, list

I created a directory site, but I used normal posts, and builder modules in post content to get the desired directory post layout, however i realized that using builder modules in post content was a mistake, because of the "lock-in" effect, that is, if I remove or change my site builder, I'll have to remake all my post content.

The desired post content layout is simple: 1 directory item would consist of 1 element consisting of 3 sub-blocks: item image, item title and item description, the elements organized in 2 columns. (This so far I achieved with builder modules, but that was wrong :( )

The plan is to make 1 element 1 post in which the image block would be the featured image, the item title block would be the post title, and the item description would be the post excerpt.

So the directory post content would be displayed via a post type archive, and I would use post type categories and parent categories for the gallery filter (1 gallery image is a post type featured image), and said gallery would display my directory posts on my index page.

So far so good, but does this mean that I will need to create a custom template for each post type (directpory post) containing the posts (directory post items)?

Because every of my post types (actual posts) will have to display a different archive. How do I specify that and where?

Somehow my Wordpress intelligence stopped here and I can't bring the plan further. Any ideas?

Comment: You've pretty much got it, I think. I'd recommend reading up on the Template Hierarchy - that will explain what templates you need to create. This is a good article: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/wordpress-template-hierarchy-explained/  For example you'd create an archive.php template to handle the default post type, then an archive-custom_post_type.php for the CPT. You may also be interested in learning about Template Parts: https://wpshout.com/get-template-part/

Comment: Hi Michelle, thanks! In the meanwhile I decided to not ditch my page builder and its template builder for the templates, I only want to ditch buildr modules in my post content, for start. This is my post tmeplate 
 structure built with site bulder: https://i.imgur.com/mHMTHV9.png

Comment: I just want to replace the "Post Content" builder module with a "Post Types Archive" builder module, and specify a dynamic query in the module to match dynamically the proper archive on every post. How do I do that association? If I give the same title for the post type category wanted in the archive as for the post title where said archive is wanted, will WP Query do the matching automatically? If not, how do I specify the matching in the query? Or how do I do the associacion so that a dynamic query can be written for it? based on titles, based on IDs?

Comment: Post Type Archives don't have titles like posts do, so I must use the post type category title to match the post title where I want the archive displayed, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin (template builder) you're using, so I can't answer this question, sorry. You may want to go onto the plugin's forums to ask for help since this seems to be specific to that plugin. If you are actually editing the theme files directly, please post your code so we can give more specific direction. Thanks!